# What land routes can I choose to get to Tajikistan from Iran, passing through Afghanistan?

Tags: routes, taxis, iran, tajikistan, afghanistan

My general plan is to take a shared taxi from the Iran-Afghanistan border, then pass through Afghanistan to get to Tajikistan.

Which routes do you suggest to see the most cities and places in the north of Afghanistan plus Kabul in the shortest time?

Comment: Please stay safe.

Comment: Sure! Safety is very important and I will appreciate users who try to consider it in their answers.

Comment: @hippietrail Thank you very much for edit! By your helps I am going to improve my English in every SE site too! :)

Comment: خواهش می‌کنم (-;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't have your own transport, your mobility will be very limited.

It still makes sense to avoid Kandahar, for safety reasons, though you do speak Persian (it appears), which will make you blend in more.

So, your most sensible route would be Herat -> Mazar -> Baghlan -> Tajikistan. You could head down from Baghlan to Kabul and back to visit Kabul.

It's a bit of a detour and requires your own vehicle, really, but Bamyan is very much worth it.

Comment: I have to take cabs,taxis etc and yes! Surely south of Afghanistan is dangerous. Even I have read and heard Taliban are active around Kabul again recently. Agree! It is an advantage that I have as I talk Persian/Farsi but with a different dialects that Afghan people talk.